# Merge multiple ajax responses in one array

Tags: jquery, ajax, response

I have implemented dropzone.js in one website. When I drop multiple files in a div, dropzone.js sends one request at a time which is good for php performance and file upload limit.

However the downside of it is that I could not figure out how to catch all responses and merge them in a single array. In my array I can only save the value of the last response.

Here is my code:

```js
$("#dropzoneJs").dropzone({
  maxFiles: 2000,
  success: function(file, response) {
    var array = [];
    $.each(response, function() {
      $.each(this, function(k, v) {
        v = response.data.image;
        console.log(v);
        array.push(v);
      });
    });

    var array1 = JSON.stringify(array);
    $('#fdata').val(array1);
  }
});
```

I dragged two different files and when i save the two responses in an array i get only the last response in that array multiplied by two times.

```
["/images/aluguer/1.jpg","/images/aluguer/1.jpg"]
```

What i need is:

```
["/images/aluguer/1.jpg","/images/aluguer/2.jpg"]
```

Console.log output (don't mind red errors they are not related):

[image]

Comment: The inner loop looks like it repeatedly refers to the same item: `response.data.image`. I realize that `response` is an iterated value, but I can't imagine that you're getting multiple responses back? I may be wrong though. Can you include a snippet of what your response looks like?

Comment: If i made console.log(v) it writes the 2 diferent files, but prefixed by a 2, which means the loop is running twice in each image, and only the two iterations of the last response is saved in array. As a consequence i have the same last response saved twice in the array.

Comment: If you could include a snippet of what a response might look like, it would be much easier to debug.

Comment: `v = response.data.image;` doesn't make sense. At the very least, remove that line.

Comment: I updated the question with console.log screen capture.

Comment: response.data.image is the image path inside the object response.

Comment: Right, but, that line still doesn't make sense knowing that. That line essentially makes the .each useless.

Comment: What do you get with `console.log(response);`?

Comment: With console.log(response) i get 2 equal objects for each image. Its because of the loop.

Comment: I mean _outside_ of the loop... like just before your `array = []`; and share the exact response of `console.log(response)`, please :)

Comment: /images/aluguer/1.jpg,/images/aluguer/2.jpg

Comment: Sorry i made a mistake: response is the 2 diferent images dragged. in 2 separated calls

Comment: Call 1 has the 1st image and call 2 has the 2nd image

Comment: why you pass a variable to assign a value to it and then push it into the array? `function(k, v) { v = response.data.image;`... try `console.log(response.data.image);` and `array.push(response.data.image);`

Comment: array.push(response.data.image) without loop saves only the last response image path. With loop save only the last response image path two times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare the array outside the function, otherwise you're starting from an empty array each time it's used.

```
var dropZoneArray = [];

$("#dropzoneJs").dropzone({
  maxFiles: 2000,
  success: function(file, response) {
    $.each(response, function() {
      $.each(this, function(k, v) {
        v = response.data.image;
        console.log(v);
        dropZoneArray.push(v);
      });
    });

    var array1 = JSON.stringify(dropZoneArray);
    $('#fdata').val(array1);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. That was the issue.